# cv2.imwrite() SystemError: <built-in function imwrite> returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: python, opencv

I'm tring to save an np array as an image. The problem is that, if I write the path in the imwrite function it works, but if i store it in a variable and then use this variable as path it doesn't work and returns an error.

This works:

```
cv2.imwrite('my/path/to/image.png', myarray[...,::-1])
```

This doesn't work

```
new_image_path = path/'{}+.png'.format(np.random.randint(1000))
cv2.imwrite(new_image_path, myarray[...,::-1])
```

And it returns this error:

```
SystemError: <built-in function imwrite> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Comment: `new_image_path` is a `Path`…?! Perhaps `imwrite` requires it to be a string…?

Comment: The path in `cv2.imwrite` cannot be a `Path`. Wrap your `Path` object in `str()` and it shall work.

Comment: Please past directly from code, rather than trying to retype. Both of those fragments have syntax errors due to missing single quotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method `cv2.imwrite` does not work with the Path object. Simply convert it to string when you call the method:

```
cv2.imwrite(str(new_image_path), myarray[...,::-1])
```